# Python Tkinter: Why does "1.end" work but not "2.0"?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have the following Python 3 code, using Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class Foo:
    def replace(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.text_field.replace("1.end", END, "\n" + "New Line 2")
    def create_gui(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.text_field = Text(height = 30, width = 70)
        self.text_field.pack()
        self.text_field.insert(END, "Line 1" + "\n" + "Line 2" + "\n" + "Line 3")

        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_object = Foo()
    threading.Thread(target = foo_object.replace, daemon = True).start()
    foo_object.create_gui()
```

In this version of the code, everything works as expected; a window appears with a text field that shows

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

One second later, it becomes

```
Line 1
New Line 2
```

However, if I change the `"1.end"` in line 8 to `"2.0"`, the code does not work as intended. Approximately 2 seconds after the original window appears on my screen, it closes itself, without ever having replaced the text.

New code:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

class Foo:
    def replace(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.text_field.replace("2.0", END, "\n" + "New Line 2")
    def create_gui(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.text_field = Text(height = 30, width = 70)
        self.text_field.pack()
        self.text_field.insert(END, "Line 1" + "\n" + "Line 2" + "\n" + "Line 3")

        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_object = Foo()
    threading.Thread(target = foo_object.replace, daemon = True).start()
    foo_object.create_gui()
```

I would think that calling `self.text_field.replace("2.0", END, "\n" + "New Line 2")` would simply replace all of the text from the beginning of the second line onward with the new text (`"\n" + "New Line 2"`), but it does not. It behaves completely differently than when using `self.text_field.replace("1.end", END, "\n" + "New Line 2")`, which works correctly.

Why does my second code example (using `"2.0"`) behave in this way?

**Note:** This problem only occurs when calling Foo's replace() function from a different thread.

Comment: The answer is probably "because tkinter isn't thread safe". Some versions are, but I'm not sure if there's any way to tell if your version is or isn't unless you specifically compiled the tcl/tk libraries with thread support. Also, it's important to know that `1.end` and `2.0` refer to different locations in the widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, they refer to different locations in the widget, but they should both accomplish the same task in my code. I am still confused as to why `1.end` works but not `2.0`; I would think that either both of them would work or neither of them would.

Comment: If it's a threading issue, the behavior can be somewhat nondeterministic.